# CloudFront and mod_pagespeed - wrong content received

Tags: apache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, mod-pagespeed

I am using CloudFront with mod_pagespeed running on the server.

When updating a CSS or flushing the cache I see problematic behavior, first refresh on the browser returns the original css (this is fine). When I refresh a second time I get the correct manipulated CSS file name but the content of the file from CloudFront is still the original and not the correct manipulated content.

Why would this happen?
Any idea how to fix this?

**Update:**

For some reason it just stopped happening... I don't know why.

Comment: mod_pagespeed should generate a new filename for the new CSS file - are you refreshing the old filename? The new file should be the one picked up by CloudFront as well...

Comment: @igrigorik, That's my point exactly. The request **is** for the **new** generated filename, but the **old** content is received with the new filename. It happens only through CF.

Answer (score 1):

SimonW, since your original post there has been a feature added to pagespeed (in March 2013 in version 1.2.24.1) to deal with this issue directly. The directive is enabled via the following:

Apache:
ModPagespeedRewriteDeadlinePerFlushMs deadline_value_in_milliseconds

Nginx:
pagespeed RewriteDeadlinePerFlushMs deadline_value_in_milliseconds;

The docs describe the directive as follows (emphasis mine):

> When PageSpeed attempts to rewrite an uncached (or expired) resource
>   it will wait for up to 10ms per flush window (by default) for it to
>   finish and return the optimized resource if it's available. If it has
>   not completed within that time the original (unoptimized) resource is
>   returned and the optimizer is moved to the background for future
>   requests. The following directive can be applied to change the
>   deadline. Increasing this value will increase page latency, but might
>   reduce load time (for instance on a bandwidth-constrained link where
>   it's worth waiting for image compression to complete). **Note that a
>   value less than or equal to zero will cause PageSpeed to wait
>   indefinitely.**

So, if you specify a value of 0 for deadline_value_in_milliseconds you should always get the fully optimized page. I would caution that the latency can be high on this in some cases. I my case, I really wanted this behavior, even with the latency concern, because the content was to be cached on my CDN's edge servers and, thus, I wanted the most optimized version possible to be served to the CDN for caching.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have multiple backend servers and CloudFront is hitting a different one than the HTML request went through. In that case the resource was rewritten on the HTML server, but not on the other server. There is a short timeout and if the other server doesn't finish the rewrite in that time, it will just serve the original content with `Cache-Control: private,max-age=300`. It's possible CloudFront caches that for a little while (even though obviously it shouldn't), but then eventually re-requests the resource from your backend and gets the correctly rewritten version this time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. At least in my case this wasn't the issue as I had only 1 server...